# Import tkinter/Tkinter as "Tk" or "tk"?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've seen the light an will now convert all my tkinter references from `Canvas` to `Tk.Canvas`, from `Label` to `tk.Label`, and from `root = Tk()` to `root = tk.Tk()`, etc.

Stuck in between Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5 my program stub looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    import tkinter as Tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    import tkinter.font as font
except ImportError: # Python 2
    import Tkinter as Tk
    import ttk
    import tkFont as font
```

The question is should I be using `import tkinter as Tk` or `import tkinter as tk`?

I'm thinking the latter but I would like to stick to industry standards. Also take into consideration how most answers are written in **Stack Overflow**. Going with this majority means I can try code snippets with the least modifications.

The advantage I see using `import tkinter as tk` is:

- Tkk is imported as `ttk` so there is capitalization consistency.
- tkFont is imported as `font` so there is capitalization consistency.

I'm still on my first Python project and want to develop good reusable code for future projects.

Comment: This is totally up to you and you shouldn't waste much time thinking about it.

Comment: Being consistent is about the only thing that matters here, imo.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Do you use `Tk` or `tk`?

Comment: @kopecs Do you use `Tk` or `tk`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I think I use `tk`, but to be honest I mostly write C/C++/Rust nowadays and even writing python I avoid tkinter like the plague. (This would also probably be better suited to chat and not comments).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm not sure what you mean by the **snake_case** are you saying you would use `tk_.Label` vs `Tk.Label`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix snake_case just refers to using underscores as a delimiting character between words. In your example it would be `tk.Label`.

Comment: @kopecs Yes tkinter versus other options is opinion based. For myself I used the built-in python which has the built in Tkinter. This allows me to write tools other Ubuntu 16.04 (and greater) users can enjoy without having to `sudo apt install` a third party packages. That said they still have to install Pillow for my first project.

Comment: @kopecs I don't think the **snake_case** issue applies here. Neither does the **camel_code** even if we are talking `tk.` vs. `Tk.`. It would be interesting to get SO word counts on `Tk.Label` vs `tk.Label`. That tells us what the majority are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is should I be using `import tkinter as Tk` or `import tkinter as tk`?

You should use `import tkinter as tk`, based on the naming conventions in [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I've seen people in Stack Overflow use `Tk.Xxxx` instead of `tk.Xxxx` for Q&A's many years old so it's nice to know which method is preferred. Do you view the question as nonsensical / trivial as some might think? Initially I imported `*` so everything was `Label(...)` or `Frame(,,,)` I'm glad now it is imported as `tk` so something like `var = tk.StringVar()` is more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, you generally import tkinter and use Tk
This syntax is used to avoid potential naming conflicts in your code. It imports the tkinter module and renames it to tk for convenience. Then, you use tk.Tk() to create an instance of the Tk class.

```
import tkinter as tk
top = tk.Tk()
```

If you're using Python 2, you would import it as Tkinter and use Tk

```
import Tkinter as tk
top = tk.Tk()
```

Comment: Upvoting because this is the way I do it and you have no upvotes yet. However, please note Brian pretty much said the same thing I believe?